# ceil() function in C does not return expected value

Tags: ceil

```
double res;
res = ceil(363.5);
```

`res` is `1031` instead of `364` as expected.

Does anyone know the reason? And how can I use the function `ceil()` and get the expected result?

Answer (score 2):

Unless you're calling a *different* `ceil()` function<sup>1</sup>, or printing the result in the wrong way, it should work fine:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main (void) {
    double res;
    res = ceil (363.5);
    printf ("%f\n", res);
    return 0;
}
```

That code outputs `364.000000` as expected. I'd suggest typing it in exactly as is to see what result you get. If it's *still* not `364`, then you have a serious problem.

---

<sup>1</sup> Such as `double ceil (double x) { return 1031.0; }` :-)